# How to run 5400 xeon series on a pre E11030-202 s5000xvn motherboard

Tags: cpu, motherboard, bios

I have an Intel s5000xvn (PBA D37261-901) motherboard running dual x5355 xeons. I was able to pick up a matched pair of x5460 xeons. Unfortunately the x5460's want a s5000xvn (pba E11030-202 or greater) motherboard.

Currently running Bios98_4, BMC66, and FSL48.

So, is there any way to run the x5460's in the D37261-901 board? I'm open to learning about  bios hacks, as this is an old tinker machine, but if there is a real hardware incompatibility
I would like to know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be a physical hardware design difference that's needed to support those newer CPUs.

The PBA numbers signify actual PCB changes, so there's no hack or BIOS change you can do to make it work, the bits and pieces needed to support that certain CPU generation/variation just aren't there.

Comment: Usually, I would agree that that is the best answer, but the same intel boards that run the 5400 series xeons also run the 5200 series.

Comment: The board in question will run 5100 series and 5300 series so maybe it has something to do with intel's tick tock and really is a hardware incompatibility.

Comment: That's why they provide the PBA numbers - to distinguish compatibility. :) Source: I worked for an Intel Premier Provider when the s5000-series was current.